# insert row with multiple keys

Tags: sql, insert

```
ID  DEPT
user1   A
user1   B
user1   C
user2   A
user2   B
user3   A
user4   A
user4   B
user4   D
user4   E
```

I want to take a table such as the one above, see which users have dept A but not C, and insert C, or vice versa (Have C, not A, insert new row with A)

In the table above for example, User4 would be identified as having A but not C, so a new row with user4 and dept C would be inserted.

Comment: please use the code tag to intelligibly format your relevat code/data samples

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: what are the columns in the table?  from what you submitted, i can't tell what the columns and what the values are

Comment: Please edit your question to include one or more of your attempts to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tablename(Id, Dept)
SELECT COALESCE(A.ID, C.ID)
,   CASE 
  WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'A'
 WHEN C.ID IS NULL THEN 'C'
END
FROM 
    (select id
    from tableName
    WHERE Dept = 'A') A
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (select id
    from tableName
    WHERE Dept = 'C') C
    ON A.Id = C.Id   
WHERE
    A.Id IS NULL OR C.Id IS NULL
```